# Pasting a URL in Adobe Illustrator is deforming it

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I have this URL: https://doi.org/10.1145/3239235.3267429 to paste in a text box in Adobe Illustrator CC 2018.

Although paragraph alignment is set to left alignment, the URL is appearing deformed as in the image (10.xxx and 3239235.xxx are misplaced)

[image: URL in illustrator]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't replicate the problem. Sorry.

Comment: By the way, "deforming" I think isn't the word. Maybe something like "messing the order..."? (and plz check my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

:') Hi Jalal! welcome to GDSE.

Ahlan Wasahlan! ;') I presume you have Arabic language installed.

First go to **CHARACTERS Panel**, and watch your "**Language**", young man! ;') (default is Arabic).

---

**In the future, for others**:
With Arabic (and other RTL, right-to-left) languages always check
**CHARACTER Panel**:

1. Language
2. Digits options
3. Font

**PARAGRAPH Panel**:

4. Paragraph direction options (the buttons
   above "Hyphenation" checkbox >>see attached image)

Weird directional stuff happens with Arabic language settings :'o (especially with numbers, marks, and Arabic and English combined!)

Don't be shy to ask for help, and also help when you can.

Maasalama! =')

[image]

//

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Lorgen for the warm welcome. I could not find the text direction buttons but it worked when I set the composition in `Paragraph` to `Adobe Single-Line Composer` like here https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/arabic-hebrew.html

Comment: Woah, didn't consider that! Thank you for sharing! :') I mostly ignore those options, really, so that's something I learned today ;')